# Is it possible to add a row number column in BigQuery External Table?

Tags: sql, csv, google-bigquery

We have a process where we receive .csv files in a GCP bucket. We have created an external table which points to that source. We want to add an extra column to the table which stores the `row number` for the each record in the file. I did some research but couldn't find a way to add this column without touching the file.

If I want to add a row_number() in the query that reads from this table, I would need a column for `order by` too but I don't have any column for that. If I don't add `order by`, the results are non-deterministic.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Any reason to try to add `row_number` even though there is no ordering column in your table ?

Comment: The files we receive are from our clients and we will validate them via our process. If one of the rows have some faulty data, we want to be able to tell them to fix XX row in their csv file.
@Jaytiger

Answer (score 1):

You can create an external table for your requirement using the csv file stored in the gcs bucket, below query can be considered:

```
Create EXTERNAL table `project-id.dataset.table` 
options (format='csv' ,uris=["gs://file-location.csv"])
```

**CSV Data:**

```
A,B,C
47803,629,785
3809, 897,657
```

To add a row_number() column, you can consider the below query.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() row_number, * from `project-id.dataset.table`
```

**Output:**

[image]